# Hitting Unexpected token < in JSON when registering app to MobileFirst server 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to register my app in SITServer using MobileFirst 8.0 by following [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_register_app_ios.html)

1) Hitting this error:

```
mfpdev app register SITServer
```

> Verifying server configuration... Error: Cannot connect to server
>   'SITServer' at 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9080'. Reason: Failed to set
>   runtime details.: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0: HTTP 404 -
>   Not Found

```
$ mfpdev server info
```

[image]

2) Is it caused by the difference in server version? My Local server version is 8.0.0-2016101416 and SITServer version is 8.0.0.00-20160822-2140

Comment: `<` is not a JSON keyword. You're obviously getting an HTML error page. Just look at it (though `HTTP 404 - Not Found` is pretty self-descriptive).

Comment: I doubt it's the server version. You need to double check the protocol, host, port, context root, admin username, admin password, etc... details that you enter when adding the SITServer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i can view the WebSphere Liberty Profile page when I type this http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9080 into my chrome browser...

Comment: @IdanAdar Since the tutorial is using https, does http protocol works? I've changed the 1) MobileFirst Operations Console context root from mfpconsole to worklightconsole 2) MobileFirst Runtime context root from mfp to /POS...I'll change it back to the default values to see if it works

Comment: @user1872384, any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this happened due to some of the changes you've made to the server.xml; you did not mention which changes you've done so I would advise to double check those (any real reason to change these?).

Either way, both HTTP and HTTPS are supported, yes.

Comment: Thx @Idan Adar, managed to solved it by changing the server setting to default values